# Json object pushed into javascript array

Tags: arrays, json, object, push

I have this javascript array:

```
var data = ([

      ['Price', 'Time'],
      ['1.10661',  1467923348, ],
      ['1.10675',  1467923349, ],
      ['1.10681',  1467923350, ],
      ['1.10690',  1467923351, ],

    ]);
```

Im sending a request to my server using ajax and Im reciving as response this json objects:

```
[{"PRICE":"1.10662","TIME":"1467923352"},{"PRICE":"1.10663","TIME":"1467923353"}]
```

What im trying to do is to parse the response and push the objects inside of my array so the final result should be this:

```
var data = ([

      ['Price', 'Time'],
      ['1.10661',  1467923348, ],
      ['1.10675',  1467923349, ],
      ['1.10681',  1467923350, ],
      ['1.10690',  1467923351, ],
      ['1.10662',  1467923352, ],
      ['1.10663',  1467923353, ],

    ]);
```

Please keep in mind the number of objets I receive as response changes in every request. In the example Im giving is received just two objects but this changes all the time.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you tried anything. SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: Provide your JS script. I'll fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can break your problem down into 2 parts. First think about how you can make the `response` data to look the same as `data`, in terms of data format. Then merge the 2 arrays into one.

Here is my approach. First use the `map` api to go through every object in `resp` and extract the property value of PRICE and TIME and store it into a new array. This should leave you with an array of array with position 0 as price and position 1 as time.

> [ [ '1.10662', '1467923352' ], [ '1.10663', '1467923353' ] ]

Then use the `concat` api to combine the 2 arrays into one.

**Example:**

```
var data = ([

  ['Price', 'Time'],
  ['1.10661',  1467923348, ],
  ['1.10675',  1467923349, ],
  ['1.10681',  1467923350, ],
  ['1.10690',  1467923351, ],

]);

var resp = [{"PRICE":"1.10662","TIME":"1467923352"},{"PRICE":"1.10663","TIME":"1467923353"}];

data = data.concat(
    resp.map(entity => { return [ entity.PRICE, entity.TIME ]; })
);
```

**Output:**

> ```
> [ [ 'Price', 'Time' ],
>   [ '1.10661', 1467923348 ],
>   [ '1.10675', 1467923349 ],
>   [ '1.10681', 1467923350 ],
>   [ '1.10690', 1467923351 ],
>   [ '1.10662', '1467923352' ],
>   [ '1.10663', '1467923353' ] ]
> ```

You might want to read more about the `map` and `concat` api here;

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for the answers! I found the solution, let me share it with you.
(The example is a bit different but the idea is exactly the same)

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body>

        <script>
        var myArray = [{"ASK":"1.10662","TIME":"1467923348"},{"ASK":"1.10663","TIME":"1467923346"},{"ASK":"1.10661","TIME":"1467923340"},{"ASK":"1.10663","TIME":"1467923346"},
        {"ASK":"1.10661","TIME":"1467923340"}];

               var data = ([

                  ['PRICE', 'TIME'],

                ]);



        var actualrows = data.length
        var finalrows = data.length + myArray.length;





        for( var i=actualrows; i<finalrows; i++ ) {
          data.push( [] );
        }

        while(actualrows < finalrows){
            var column = 0;
            while(column <2){
                data[actualrows][0] = myArray[actualrows-1]['ASK'];
                data[actualrows][1] = myArray[actualrows-1]['TIME'];;
            column++;
            }

                actualrows++ ;      
        }



        </script>



</body>
</html>
```